# Rasa Chatbot: Handling repeated scenario

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am working in follow up bot, each user has many tasks, when user ask about his/her tasks, the Bot will fetch tasks using API then the bot will displayed the tasks one by one and going to ask the user if he/she able to finish it today. if user said yes the the the task will marked as completed if no the bot will ask the user about finished date.

I tired many solution in Action by iterate over tasks and dispatch template but after dispatching the loop stop and never go back again.

```
class ActionRequestTasks(Action):

def name(self):
    return "action_request_tasks"

@staticmethod
def json2obj(data):
    return json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))

def run(self, dispatcher, tracker: DialogueStateTracker, domain):
    response = requests.get('url', headers=headers)
    tasks_wrapper = self.json2obj(response.text)
    data = tasks_wrapper.Data
    first_message = "You have {} delayed tasks, I will help you to go through all of them".format(len(data))
    dispatcher.utter_message(first_message)

    for task in data:
        task_message = "Task Title {}\nComplete percentage {}\nStart Date {}\nFinish Date{}".format(task.Title,
                                                                                                    task.PercentComplete,
                                                                                                    task.StartDate,
                                                                                                    task.FinishDate)
        dispatcher.utter_message(task_message)
        dispatcher.utter_template("utter_able_to_finish", tracker)
    return []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect application for a `Form`.  You can make the API call in the `required_slots()` method, then use [validation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/forms/#validating-user-input) to fill the slots dependent on the user's response.  The form will run until all slots are filled, then you can decide what to do with the slots in the `submit()` method (for instance, updating the task status for each one via another request).

I recommend reading the [docs on Form setup](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/forms) and also checking out the code for [formbot](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/master/examples/formbot/actions.py#L9) to see a working implementation